# Simplify by trying to merge 2 functions into only one - issue of overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I did an exclusive checkbox where I have 2 `<input>` with two `<button>` (also exclusive with black/white color) by `<input>`; below the HTML code snippet:

```
<div id="PlayerVsComputer" class="checkbox">                                        
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="game">
   <div class="btn-group" role="group"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse btn-xs">Player</button>             
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-classic btn-xs">Computer</button>           
   </div>
  </label>
 </div>
 <div id="Player1VsPlayer2" class="checkbox">                                        
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="game">
   <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse btn-xs">Player 1</button>           
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-classic btn-xs">Player 2</button>           
   </div>
  </label>
 </div>
```

Everything is working fine with the following functions (to invert color black/white for both `PlayerVsComputer` and `Player1VsPlayer2` type of game).

When mouse is out of the area of button, I did :

```
   // Restore original state when mouseleave
   $('#PlayerVsComputer').mouseleave(restore1);
   // Restore original state when mouseleave
   $('#Player1VsPlayer2').mouseleave(restore2);

   // Restore default choice for player vs computer
   function restore1() {
     buttonsPlayerVsComputer.each(function(index, value) {
     if (!$(value).prop('disabled')) {
       buttonsPlayerVsComputer.eq(0).removeClass('btn-classic').addClass('btn-inverse');
       buttonsPlayerVsComputer.eq(1).removeClass('btn-inverse').addClass('btn-classic');
   }
   });}
   
// Restore default choice for player1 vs player2
   function restore2() {
     buttonsPlayer1VsPlayer2.each(function(index, value) {
     if (!$(value).prop('disabled')) {
       buttonsPlayer1VsPlayer2.eq(0).removeClass('btn-classic').addClass('btn-inverse');
       buttonsPlayer1VsPlayer2.eq(1).removeClass('btn-inverse').addClass('btn-classic');
   }});}
```

and when mouse enters into `<div>` :

```
    // Flip buttons player vs computer color when mouse is entering
    buttonsPlayerVsComputer.mouseenter(toggle1);
    // Flip buttons player vs computer color when mouse is entering
    buttonsPlayer1VsPlayer2.mouseenter(toggle2);

 function toggle1() {
     buttonsPlayerVsComputer.each(function(index, value) {
     if (!$(value).prop('disabled')) {
       $(value).toggleClass('btn-inverse btn-classic');
     }
   });
   }

   function toggle2() {
     buttonsPlayer1VsPlayer2.each(function(index, value) {
     if (!$(value).prop('disabled')) {
       $(value).toggleClass('btn-inverse btn-classic');
     }
   });
   }
```

**Now, I would like to simplify it and merge `toggle1` and `toggle2` functions into unique toogle function**. I tried to do :

```
  // toggle black/white for both types of game 
  function toggle() {
     var element = $(this);
     element.each(function(index, value) {
     if (!$(value).prop('disabled')) {
       $(value).toggleClass('btn-inverse btn-classic');
     }
   });
   }
```

**Following the same way for doing a unique function `restore` from `restore1` an `restore2` functions**, I did :

```
// Restore default choice for both types of game
   function restore() {
     var element = $(this);
     element.each(function(index, value) {
     if (!$(value).prop('disabled')) {
       element.eq(0).removeClass('btn-classic').addClass('btn-inverse');
       element.eq(1).removeClass('btn-inverse').addClass('btn-classic');
     }
    }); 
   }
```

**Unfortunately, this simplification doesn't work**, it causes overlapping between `buttons`, `<div>` :

You can see the first solution which works (with toggle1, toggle2, restore1, and restore2):

[Version working with two functions](http://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/dwjkp5rL/8/)

You can see the other result with trying to use only 2 functions (toggle and restore) but it doesn't work :

[Version not working with only one function toggle and restore](http://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/dwjkp5rL/13/)

How can I fix this?

Comment: `function toggle() { toggle1(); toggle2(); }`?

Comment: -@Olian04 I would like rather to make a simplification that would allow me to use only one "**function toggle**", i.e a kind of "**generic**" function : then I would call it both for `buttonsPlayerVsComputer` and `buttonsPlayer1VsPlayer2` buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add element as a parameter of a function because if **this** is outside of an event listener, **this** will not return the element, but window.

Comment: I tried :                      
   `buttonsPlayerVsComputer.mouseenter(toggle(this));` or it may be simplier to put `buttonsPlayerVsComputer.mouseenter(toggle(buttonsPlayerVsComputer));` ??

Comment: You should put **$(this)** as a paramter of a function not **this**, because **this** will not return a jQuery object.

Comment: -@Tomas Kudlac I tried your solution on http://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/dwjkp5rL/18/ but this doesn't seem to work, I mean black/white inverting between buttons is not performed

Comment: -@Tomas Kudlac Could you give please an example of what I should do ?